# plot time series dataframe and mark certain points using pandas and matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe storing a time series, which looks like as follows. How to plot it using time column as `x-axis`. Moreover, if I want to mark certain points between a given time period, e.g., `2014-11-18` to `2015-1-30`. How to do that using `matplotlib`?

[image]

This is what I did, but it appears pretty small, and how to add some marks over the certain time period?

[image]

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi Yuca, I have modified the original post, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easiest way to do this is to plot twice, the second plot having the extra style. Regarding the plot size, you can control the `figsize` parameter. Just set a tuple with the height and width you like

```
# make sure index is in datetime format
df_id_ts.index = pd.to_datetime(df_id_ts.index, figsize=(10,6))
ax = df_id_ts.plot()
df_id_ts['2014-11-18' : '2015-01-30'].plot(ax = ax, marker = 'ro')
```

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to make the plot in jupyter-notebook bigger, currently, it is very hard to see the details.