# Matplotlib Read in time as value from CSV

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, time

I am new to python coding but have been playing for a while
I build out a reader that takes Amp readings from my circuit breaker box and want to graph it

I am trying to graph date from a CSV file using matplotlib.
I am reading in a CSV file like this:(this is a small sample I take a reading every minute)

```
03:59:01,1,0.000,2,0.000,3,0.000,4,0.622,
04:00:01,1,12.000,2,0.000,3,0.000,4,0.627,
```

I am only looking in column 0 (time) and column 3 (values)
I know time is not an INT so it will not imported it IE: I get

`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '03:59:55'`

How can I convert it when it reads it in so that I can?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import csv
x = []
y = []
# read in file  columns 0 and 2
with open('bob1.csv','r') as csvfile:
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    next(plots)
    for row in plots:
        x.append(int(row[0]))
        y.append(float(row[2]))

plt.plot(x,y, label='Loaded from file!')
plt.savefig('test7.png',dpi=720)
```

I have done some basic google searching but nothing read stood out to assist in what I was doing.
I know there a tons of why to do this. So if anybody has some time and would like to assist me in get this code better I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you

Comment: Try to look into pandas, converting your csv into a dataframe and later on you can plot everything easier. With Pandas you can select your index, which will be the column with the time, and then you can plot your desired column

Comment: Related: https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51826132/plot-time-series-dataframe-and-mark-certain-points-using-pandas-and-matplotlib and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45975846/wrong-labels-when-plotting-a-time-series-pandas-dataframe-with-matplotlib could be usefull

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

csv_data = pd.read_csv('bob1.csv', index_col= 'Time')
data = pd.DataFrame(csv_data)

plt.xlabel('Time')
wathever = plt.plot(data['Unnamed: 1'], 'k', label='')
plt.title('')
plt.legend(title='')
plt.show(block=True)
```

Add a row with some text which will be your index. Then, `index_col= 'Time'`, Time is the text that I added as label in the time series. If you don't add a name in the rest of columns, Automatically pandas will consider `Unnamed: number`. You can also add a name for the column, and then instead of `'Unnamed:1'`, add the name of the column.

For example, if you create the following df:

[image]

Which is:

```
Time,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H
03:59:01,1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0.62
04:00:01,1,12,2,0,3,0,4,0.63
```

Then, instead of `'Unnamed: 1'`, you need to type `'A'`

Comment: so CSV_Data is reading in the file and setting and index. Then Data = is taking that and having Panda build out a Data from. With the wathever I am a little lost. Unamed should equal one of the other column heading, What is 'k' doing label is the label. but then wathever is never getting plugged into anything to do anything and were are we definning the x and y axis

Comment: For `csv_data` read https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html, and to create the data frame (`data`) https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html

Comment: I already set the column `'Time'` as index, so you don't need to specify anymore which is `x` or `y` because `'Time'` it's already your `x`. Just plot the column desired in the dataframe. If you don't add a name, will be `'Unnamed: number'`, where `number` correspond to the column number (0 == A, 1 == B),...

Comment: Thank you all got it working! Next step formatting the X ticks way to many values displaying need to limit it to just each Hour